# How to include A focexec in another focexec in WebFocus?

Tags: focus, mainframe, webfocus

What is the actual syntax to add a INCLUDE focexec in another focexec? I am new to WebFocus.

Can any one please tell me why I am getting this error:

```
"ERROR: ERROR_MR_FEX_NOT_FOUND Can't create item object based on provided item key FRCSTDAT.fex."
```

when I am trying to include the file inside another focexec code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WebFOCUS 8 you need to include files using the full IBFS path

```
-INCLUDE IBFS:/WFC/Repository/[folder]/[fexName].fex
```

You can find the full path by right clicking on the procedure you want to include in Dev Studio or the WF portal and selecting properties.

*Note that the properties window will reference the environment in this path, which must be excluded in the actual include.*

For example, the properties will show:
Parent Folder: IBFS:/**WF8 Dev**/WFC/Repository/[rest of path]

Exclude the bolded portion in your path for the include to work

Comment: Hey Ram,
actually I am using webfocus Managed Reporting in which I have created a focexec(say VOINVDAT) and another focexec( say FRCSTDAT). I want to include the focexec(FRCSTDAT) in the focexec(VOINVDAT).

But when I am going to do that and running the focexec VOINVDAT ,I am getting the error as "ERROR: ERROR_MR_FEX_NOT_FOUND Can't create item object based on provided item key FRCSTDAT.fex." .

Now please suggest how could I resolve this issue.

Comment: You should add that information to your question, not leave it in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Long time I didn't use manage reporting!

Try the following.

- Locate your second procedure and click Properties, and in the windows, search for "filename", must have something like xxx/yyy/fffff.fex. i.e /app/ibisamp/thefex.fex
- Open the editor with your first procedure and call the another fex with the path you had, in my case (In uppercase):

-INCLUDE /APP/IBISAMP/THEFEX.FEX

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Your one .fex needs to be able to see or reach the other .fex.  Go to the Properties panel and check to see if the locations of both .fexs are present in the Application path.  Then try the -INCLUDE statement.